# SetResult not working when activity finished by clearTop

Tags: android, android-activity

**Overview of Problem**: ActivityA starts ActivityB with `startActivityForResult`. ActivityB sets its result using `setResult` and then starts ActivityC with `startActivity`. ActivityC then starts the `singleTop` ActivityA with the `CLEAR_TOP` flag set. I expect this to finish ActivityB and call ActivityA's `onActivityResult` method. Unfortunately this method is not getting called upon the restart of ActivityA.

---

**ActivityA Code**: I have started an activity (ActivityB) with `startActivityForResult()` with the following code from ActivityA:

```
....
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);   
....
```

The following code in ActivityA waits for the result:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == ACTIVITY_RESULT){ 
        doSomethingSpecial();
    }
}
```

**ActivityB Code**:  I have a confirmation dialog. When the user clicks "Yes" they will set the Result of this activity, which

```
private void showConfirmationDialog(String message, final String username) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setMessage(message)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);

            setResult(ActivityA.ACTIVITY_RESULT);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    alert.show();
}
```

**ActivityC Code**: When ready, the following code is called upon a button click in ActivityC:

```
private void startActivityA(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I am expecting the `doSomethingSpecial()` function in ActivityA to be called, but this is not occurring.

**NB**: Just as an aside, if the ActivityB code is replaced, and instead of starting ActivityC from the dialog, finish() is called–i.e. ActivityC is never opened and B is simply closed, then `doSomethingSpecial()` is indeed called. Therefore this problem seems to stem from some lack of understanding of the functionality of the back stack and clear top.

Any assistance would be appreciated as to why this is not behaving as desired! I have come up with a number of hacks around this, but am most interested as to why this is occurring in order to improve my understanding of the activity stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that from a user's perspective it will feel very strange that you are "starting" a previous activity (A) from a later activity (C), instead of just "going back" to it.

I believe you should start C from B with `startActivityWithResult()`. Then when activity C is done call `finish()`. In B's `onActivityResult()` call `setResult()` and then `finish()`.

Comment: I was discussing from the code point of view. For the user it does feel like going back, but ActivityB is an intermediary activity that the user would not expect to return to. I thought the purpose of starting an activity with the clear_top flag set is precisely to do this: go back to a previous activity and clear all the activities that came afterwards

Comment: I'm not sure why you expected the `onActivityResult` of A to be called when you *started* it from activity C. In any case, if you're set in your ways, you can just do it the other way. Pass the result you want from B -> C then from C -> A.

Comment: OK this is what I was missing. I was expecting `onActivityResult` in A to be called when C reopened A with `CLEAR_TOP` and thereby closing B, but it seems as though this reopening will **not** call the onActivityResult method because this method only gets called upon going BACK from B to A. I expected this to be called because I didn't really view this as so much a restarting as a closing of two subsequent activities and then a reopening, but I guess it still is a restarting of activityA.