# Getting activity result after CLEAR_TOP

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

I have an issue very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126125/setresult-not-working-when-activity-finished-by-cleartop). I have activity (A) starting activity (B) that can start another instance of activity (B) that can start any number of consecutive instances of itself. (The user can navigate back and forth on a kind of tree).

I want the user to be able to push a button that will take him to activity (A) while clearing all instances of activity(B) but still returning **the result of the 1st instance of activity (B)**.

Adding `Intent intent = new Intent(InstanceOfActivityB.this,ActivityA.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` gives me the right behavior, however activity (A) doesn't receive the result from the first instance of activity (B).

I have also tried to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT` to pass along the result of the first instance of (B) to the last. However the user navigates forward in the line of instances of (B) activities by clicking on an item in a listview from the current instance, and back by pressing the back key. So a new instance of activity (B) is started from a custom array adaptor. Maybe that's why my result isn't being passed forward.

I know this is a very specific issue but any help would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT:** I just tried using shared preferences to save the result, realized that activity (A) gets reset when calling it with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. Maybe I should start activity (B) in another task and kill that entire task when user wants to go back to activity (A).

Answer (score 0):

If your Activity B can start its own instances then i would suggest you to use it's `launchMode` as `singleTop`. Since B is on top and you again start B then it won't create a new instance rather it'll give you the same instance and you can handle the code in `onNewIntent()`.

`A - > B - > New Instance of B created.`

`A - > B - > B - > onNewIntent() called, new instance NOT created.`

As per the docs:

`If an instance of the activity already exists at the top of the target task, the system routes the intent to that instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance of the activity.`

Comment: Good idea, but I don't think I can use it. The user needs to be able to navigate back and forth through the instances of activity (B), the way I achieved this is through the use of multiple instances of acitivity (B). This tree the user navigates must be dynamic, otherwise I would have created different activities for each branch. In the end I think the only option left is to save my result in a shared preference and be done with it. (unless I find a more elegant solution)